# Apache sub-route/symlink exceptions-to-the-rule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, url-routing

I don't know how to describe this problem without a specific setup, so I'm not sure if the post title is very meaningful.

Anyway, we have a Rails app called `marketing` running on Phusion Passenger.  We have the Passenger `VirtualHost` set up with a `RailsBaseURI /marketing` entry, and the `/var/www/html/marketing` symlink that points to the Rails directory in a separate part of the file system (say `/home/user1/marketing`).  This all works fine, and we can hit the app at `ourdomain.com/marketing`.  The Rails app has a couple of routes like `/marketing/businesses` and `/marketing/certificates` that point to different "subapps" corresponding to various functionalities of our marketing division.

Now, I have a standalone Adobe AIR app called `MarketingPeanuts` that supports the AIR autoupdate feature.  In short, the autoupdate requires the AIR installer package and a config file on the server ("autoupdate contents"), and the AIR application code points to this URL.  I would like the URL for the autoupdate to be `ourdomain.com/marketing/peanuts` to maintain semantics.  However, I do not want to put the autoupdate contents into the Rails directory because 1) the `MarketingPeanuts` AIR app is not related in any way to the Rails app (other than being another function of the marketing division), and 2) any time I need to update the AIR app, I would have to redeploy the Rails app just to get the most recent autoupdate contents onto the server.

So what I want to do is put the AIR autoupdate contents in a completely different part of the filesystem (say `/home/user2/marketing_peanuts`), and somehow tell Apache that if it sees the specific sub-URL `/marketing/peanuts`, point to this location, otherwise, send all other `/marketing/*` sub-URLs to the Rails directory (`/home/user1/marketing` from above).  All while not having Rails complain about the non-existent route (although if Apache can solve this problem, then the Rails problem shouldn't even exist).

Is it possible to do this kind of thing in Apache (I'm guessing yes), and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) (which ships with Apache). Enable the module, then put this somewhere in your Apache config:

```
Alias /marketing/peanuts /home/user2/marketing_peanuts
```